# How to use subprocess and PowerBI CMDlets within Python to keep terminal open to save more commands?

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, subprocess, azure-powershell

**The Problem:**
Subprocess Terminal does not stay open and logs off Azure Service Account before letting me put in Azure Powershell Commands.

**Python Code**

```
import subprocess

Login = subprocess.Popen(['powershell', '-command', 'Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

Workspaces = subprocess.Popen(['powershell', '-command', 'Get-PowerBIWorkspace'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# PowerShell command to get all activities for the past 30 days
ps_get_activities_cmd = '''
$enddate = get-date
$startdate = $enddate.AddDays(-30)
$startdateformat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"
$enddateformat = "yyyy-MM-ddT23:59:59"

for ($x = $startdate.AddDays(1); $x -lt $enddate; $x=$x.AddDays(1))
    {
        Write-Output ","
        Get-PowerBIActivityEvent -StartDateTime $x.ToString($startdateformat) -EndDateTime $x.ToString($enddateformat)
    }
'''

# Store PowerShell output into a variable
ps_activity_output = subprocess.run(['powershell', '-command', ps_get_activities_cmd], capture_output=True, text=True)
```

You can see I am logging in through Azure Powershell, however I cannot input any more commands to the same terminal to store different results due to terminal closing.

**Expectation**
Use subprocess similar to keeping a terminal open to keep inputting commands. This is needed due to Azure Service Account needs.

Answer (score 0):

> **Expectation** Use subprocess similar to keeping a terminal open to keep inputting commands.

You can use below code to do the same:

```
import subprocess as sp

rithwik_b = sp.Popen(['powershell', '-command', 'Connect-AzAccount -subscriptionid "b83c1ed3"'], stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE, text=True)
rithwik_b1 = sp.Popen(['powershell', '-command', 'Get-AzResourceGroup -Name "xxx"'], stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE, text=True)

while True:
    user_input = input("Rithwik enter a PowerShell command (or type 'exit' to quit the terminal): ")
    if user_input.lower() == 'exit':
        rithwik_b.stdin.write('exit\n')
        rithwik_b1.stdin.write('exit\n')
        break
    if not rithwik_b.stdin.closed and not rithwik_b1.stdin.closed:
        rithwik_b.stdin.write(user_input + '\n')
        rithwik_b1.stdin.write(user_input + '\n')
result = rithwik_b.communicate()[0]
print(result)
result1 = rithwik_b1.communicate()[0]
print(result1)
rithwik_b.wait()
rithwik_b1.wait()
```

**`Output:`**

Both commands got executed:

[image]
You can integrate the Power Bi commands according to your requirement.

Comment: Hi RithwikBojja ,

It doesn't seem to work with Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount. When this CMDlet is imputed, There is a pop up for me to login in with my credentials.

Below are the lines I edited.  

```rithwik_b = sp.Popen(['powershell', '-command', 'Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount'], stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE, text=True)
  
rithwik_b1 = sp.Popen(['powershell', '-command', 'Get-PowerBIWorkspace'], stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE, text=True)```

Comment: Yes, a pop will come you need to click on account then only it will run. The connect command gives you a pop up. It's natural. My code works for sure. I would suggest you to try in powershell terminal with those commands, then you will understand how a powrershell command works, then you can integrate powershell with python.

Comment: Yes I test in PowerShell to ensure I get all my necessary outputs. I believe your command works on your end, however it does not work using your script when changing to my actual PowerBI cmdlets.
![](https://imgur.com/a/NSCxzrC)
Get-PowerBIWorkspace : Login first with Login-PowerBIServiceAccoun
 @RithwikiBojja